# How to Query for Custom Schedule States through the API

Tags: rally

In Rally as a Workspace admin, you can add values to the drop down list for the Schedule State field on User Story (or Defect).

Is there a way through the API to be able to query for the drop down list values for Schedule State on User Stories?

The problem I am trying to solve, is that we have custom reports that we are using on various workspaces, however there is now a desire for one of the workspaces to have states prior to Defined and after Accepted. Rather than building new versions of each custom report for each workspace to handle the custom states, I would much rather query for the valid Schedule States for User Stories in that workspace and then do whatever needs to be done for displaying states in the custom reports.

For what it is worth, this is in v1.43, as these custom reports run outside of Rally using the LoginKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an AppSDK 1.33 example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="Name" content="App Example: Attribute Values" />
   <title>Attribute Values Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.43"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  function attributeQueryExample() {

     var showAttributeValues = function(results) {
      var aDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");
      aDiv.innerHTML = '<b>attributeQueryExample</b><br>';
      for (var property in results) {
        aDiv.innerHTML += "&nbsp;<b>" + property + "</b><br>";
        for (var i=0 ; i < results[property].length ; i++) {
          aDiv.innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + results[property][i] + "<br>";
        }
      }
     }; 

    var queryConfig = [];
    queryConfig[0] = {type: 'Hierarchical Requirement', 
            key : 'storyStates', 
            attribute: 'Schedule State'
            };
        queryConfig[1] = {type: 'Defect', 
            key : 'defectStates', 
            attribute: 'Schedule State'
            };

    var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('1111', '2222','false', 'false'); 
    rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showAttributeValues);
   }

   rally.addOnLoad(attributeQueryExample);

   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! - I was thinking that there was something like the State field (https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#State) but for ScheduleState, which would not only show allowed values, but whether one was enabled previously but was then disabled - but it seems like that must not exist for ScheduleState.

Answer (score 3):

This code will give you an array of all the available schedule states for User Stories. Specify a workplace OID to get the different values for different workspaces.

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
    context: {
        workspace: '/workspace/12345'
    },
    success: function(model) {
        var stateNames = Ext.Array.pluck(model.getField('ScheduleState').allowedValues, 'StringValue');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Conner! Thanks for the fast response, however unfortunately I am not using the SDK2.0, as the reports in question run outside of Rally using the LoginKey (and as I understand it this is not available in SDK2.0). - Do you have a way to do this in the SDK1.32 (using API v1.43)?